# How to reduce the time consumption of gst_element_query_position and gst_element_seek

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

My video player is use GStreamer API, I need to constantly calibrate the current playback position according to the playback strategy (through seek operation), so I need to obtain the video playback position frequently and seek operation according to the actual situation. However, when** gst_element_query_position** and **gst_element_seek** are called, the time consumed is about 100-300ms, which is too low for me. I need to keep the time under 100 milliseconds. Is there any solution?

The functions of the player are as follows

```
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=10s_30fps_1912x1080.mp4 ! decodebin ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA ! fakesink t. ! queue ! autovideosink
```

I already try gst_clock_get_time, when stream is started, take a timestamp, and when do seek, adjust this timestamp, but seek still cost 100-200ms.